# How to use this code to save the images inside my android camera app?

Tags: java, android, camera, storage

I built my own camera so it could be launched from inside my other android app, i want to save the images inside this app and not in the default gallery, i was using getExternalFilesDir() because i wanna keep the data just inside my app. But it is not working quite right, does anybody know what i have to change?? I do have the permission in my manifest.
My phone is an HTC phone

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

    imageURI = getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

    File mFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
    if(!mFile.exists()) {
        try{
            mFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e){
            return;
        }
    }

    //Uri iURI = Uri.parse(imageURI);
    Log.v("camera", mFile.toString()); // Debugging statement
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mFile));
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);

}
```

Here is the code that i am using to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the images from gallery you should create .nomedia file in the folder with images, or create your own camera app.

Comment: I did create my own camera app, and i want to save the images inside of this app. that is what my code is failing to do

Comment: can you post the error log? what sort of errors are you receiving?   did you look through this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html) of using camera api?